# Transition on path in d3.js is not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to make a transition on a path in d3.js. When a user clicks on a button, there should be a transition on the path from the beginning to the end of the path.

I try to do that with this code:

```js
const lineGraph = d3.select("svg")
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", "M 10 80 C 40 10, 65 10, 95 80 S 150 150, 180 80");

const length = lineGraph.node().getTotalLength();

lineGraph
  .attr("stroke-dasharray", length + " " + length)
  .transition()
  .duration(2000)
  .ease(d3.easeLinear);
```

```css
path {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  fill: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

The path shows up on the screen, but there is no transition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you need to transition *from* something *to* something else. In the case of making a path appear, that is from stroke-dasharray `0 length` to `length length`:

```js
const lineGraph = d3.select("svg")
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", "M 10 80 C 40 10, 65 10, 95 80 S 150 150, 180 80");

const length = lineGraph.node().getTotalLength();

lineGraph
  .attr("stroke-dasharray", "0 " + length)
  .transition()
  .duration(2000)
  .ease(d3.easeLinear)
  .attr("stroke-dasharray", length + " " + length);
```

```css
path {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  fill: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```